# How do I use case statement to aid altering another field?

Tags: sql, ms-access, case, temp-tables

I have a hopefully pretty simple question here. I'm converting some Access SQL script into Server Management Studio 2008.

Currently the Access script shows the following line of code:

```
IIf([rsosourceID]) IN (254,360,446),"MoneySavingExpert" as SourceName
```

[image: Example Entries]

Basically it's creating a temporary table with four columns, if the fields match say those 3 numbers on the left then it will populate a fourth column with their new name. (To be used for grouping in a later report)

How can I do something simillar in SQL? I've tried using a Case statement but to my knowledge that will only alter the field you're looking against.

In this case I need to look at one field then using it's results alter another, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case statement can return a new column using the value of any other column(s):

```
SELECT rsoSourceID,
    rsoDescription, 
    rsoCategory,
    case when rsoSourceID in (254,360,446)
        then 'MoneySavingExpert'
        else null end as SourceName
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Chad, thanks for this. I tried using it earlier but had some issues converting the small int to varchar but it seems to be fine now (probably as I've set it in the temp table under varchar) This works perfectly, thanks.